# What is better: BASE HREF or / signal?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Im creating big sites, there are URL rewriting. So this www.mysite.com/home is valid. In case Im on something "www.mysite.com/users/thisuser" the images/css cant be loaded. The references now "design/base.css" or "design/h.gif". I heard that using this form "`/`design/h.gif" may help, but setting BASE HREF also ok. Which one should I use? Im doing ok method anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet url should start with a `/`

All the image paths should be set relative to the stylesheet, such as `../` or `./`